# Build up around top inner rim of fermenting bucket?

Tags: fermentation, hops, krausen

I have a question. This particular brew is a white IPA and brew day was a week ago. I had a violent fermentation the first night after brewing to where a lot of krausen built up, expanded the bucket outwards and spewed a little wort through the airlock. I added ferm cap and resealed the fermenter. It has been fine ever since and krausen has subsided. Gravity dropped to almost FG after just 3 days.

I checked the gravity levels after a few days and noticed a build up around the inside of the fermenting bucket rim near the top. The build up is greenish in color and kind of "gunky" looking. Ironically enough, I also got this same build up in my kettle during game the boil right after I added in the Hops.

Would anyone happen to know of this is normal and what it might be?

I've tried to add a pic, but it's not letting me...maybe size is too big.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe you need to gain some more reputation before you can post an image.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably, it's some hops residue.  The krausen must have caused it, and in any case it's not touching the wort so I would not worry about it.

Comment: Even if it was touching the wort it would be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Given the color and location, it's most likely hop residue.  Pellets end up disintegrating into mush, hence the use of hop spiders / muslin bags.  What yeast are you using that ran through fermentation that fast?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly cooler pitch temperature and keeping the fermentation temps under 80F  will keep the violent krausen to a minimum.  This  used to be a problem for me and cooler pitch temps have resolved this.